# Group column of pyspark dataframe by taking only unique values from two columns

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I want group a column based on unique values from two columns of pyspark dataframe. The output of the dataframe should be such that once some value used for groupby and if it is present in another column then it should not repeat.

```
    |------------------|-------------------|
    |   fruit          |     fruits        | 
    |------------------|-------------------|
    |    apple         |     banana        |
    |    banana        |     apple         |
    |    apple         |     mango         |
    |    orange        |     guava         |
    |    apple         |    pineapple      |
    |    mango         |    apple          |
    |   banana         |     mango         |
    |   banana         |    pineapple      |
    | -------------------------------------|
```

I have tried to group by using single column and it needs to be modified or some other logic should be required.

```
df9=final_main.groupBy('fruit').agg(collect_list('fruits').alias('values'))
```

I am getting following output from above query;

```
       |------------------|--------------------------------|
       |   fruit          |     values                     | 
       |------------------|--------------------------------|
       |  apple           | ['banana','mango','pineapple'] |
       |  banana          | ['apple']                      |
       |  orange          | ['guava']                      |
       |  mango           | ['apple']                      |
       |------------------|--------------------------------|
```

But I want following output;

```
       |------------------|--------------------------------|
       |   fruit          |     values                     | 
       |------------------|--------------------------------|
       |  apple           | ['banana','mango','pineapple'] |
       |  orange          | ['guava']                      |
       |------------------|--------------------------------|
```

Comment: This really depends on the order of your dataframe right? Am I correct to assume that if banana would be processed before apple then banana would still be there?

Comment: If once the value is grouped then from that grouped data no value should be repeated i.e. if banana comes first then it should be [banana  | ['apple','mango','pineapple'] and then [orange  | ['guava']   be the output

Comment: spark dataframes do not have a guaranteed order, does that matter for your outcome?

Comment: No. It doesn't matter for outcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a connected components problem. There are a couple ways you can go about doing this.

**1. GraphFrames**

You can use the GraphFrames package. Each row of your dataframe defines an edge, and you can just create a graph using `df` as edges and a dataframe of all the distinct fruits as vertices. Then call the `connectedComponents` method. You can then manipulate the output to get what you want.

**2. Just Pyspark**

The second method is a bit of a hack. Create a "hash" for each row like

```py
hashed_df = df.withColumn('hash', F.sort_array(F.array(F.col('fruit'), F.col('fruits'))))
```

Drop all non-distinct rows for that column

```py
distinct_df = hashed_df.dropDuplicates(['hash'])
```

Split up the items again

```py
revert_df = distinct_df.withColumn('fruit', F.col('hash')[0]) \
    .withColumn('fruits', F.col('hash')[1])
```

Group by the first column

```py
grouped_df = revert_df.groupBy('fruit').agg(F.collect_list('fruits').alias('group'))
```

You might need to "stringify" your hash using`F.concat_ws` if Pyspark complains, but the idea is the same.